# Homeomorphism and Homotopy equivaence among 3 circles with 3, 2 and 1 common point.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I need some help with the the following problem. I am not aware what technique should I use to solve the problem:

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, we denote by $S_{x,y}$ a unit circle with center at $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $. Let $X = S_{-1,0}\cup S_{1,0} \cup S_{0,\sqrt{3}}; \quad Y =  S_{-2,0}\cup S_{0,0} \cup S_{2,0}; \text{ and } Z $ the [bouquet of 3 circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(topology)).

(Q-1)Which of them are homeomorphic to each other?

(Q-2)which of them are homtotopy equivalent to each other?

It does feel like they are all homtopy equivalent to each other but none of them is homemorphic to each other, but I don't know what tool to use to prove them.

Q-3) Can we use Fundamental group to solve this problem? I have a feeling that we can use Van Kampen theorem to solve the problem but I haven't read Van Kampen's theorem yet.

Comment: To show that two spaces are not homeomorphic, we need to find some homeomorphism-invariant property that they don't have in common. As one example, in $Z$ we can remove a single point and get a non-path-connected space. Does this happen in the other two spaces?

Comment: Likewise, if we wanted to show that two spaces are not homotopy equivalent, we need to find some homotopy-invariant property that they don't have in common. The fundamental group is homotopy invariant, so as you suggest it would be great to understand the fundamental groups of these spaces! This is a bit tricky though, van Kampen isn't quite enough for all of these. It's worthwhile to think about what the $\pi_1$'s might be though, even if you can't prove it. Anyway, if you're trying to show that these spaces *are* homotopy equivalent, you'll need to actually construct homotopy equivalences.

Comment: So, in $X, Y, Z$, we can remove 3,2 and 1 points resp.  before the spaces may become non-path-connected. Won't constructing actual homotopy equivalences be a complicated work? There must be some other way to get it done.

Comment: There isn't another way, as far as I can see. Note that you'd only have to build two homotopy equivalences to show that these three spaces are homotopy equivalent. But, hint: they're not all homotopy equivalent! I'd like to correct a previous comment though: you actually can use van Kamen to find the fundamental groups of each of these, you just have to do it carefully.

Comment: Regarding homotopy equivalences: since $Z$ is path-connected, you know that the fundamental group of $Z$ does not depend on the choice of basepoint; hence, you can say $\pi_1(Z)$ is a free group on three generators (by Van Kampen's). For $X$ and $Y$, no choice of basepoint yields such a fundamental group, so definitely $Z$ is not homotopy equivalent to either $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: Of course, this also means $Z$ is not homeomorphic to $X$ nor $Y$. Regarding $X$ and $Y$, a homeomorphism must map connected components to connected components; however, the wedge sum connected component of $X$ cannot be mapped homeomorphically into a single circle (for instance, think about their Euler characteristics). Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.